# I want to change my user name

Tags: username

I do not know how to login as a different user except for guest.I want to change my user name because I misspelled it during installation. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **Settings** then **User Accounts**. 
Once you are in the User Accounts settings, Use the **Unlock** button on the top right of the window. From there, you can edit your account!
Cheers!